# OpenLayers 3 : How export map with the ScaleLine of the map visible on the .png

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers-3

It's all in the title, I would like to export a map with the scale of the map visible on the png image exported.

Here is what I have on the screen: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/39/1411732313-default.jpg

Here's what I export png: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/39/1411731619-img12180dxn777.png

I want the png image, the scale of the map is visible, as in the picture I have on the screen with OpenLayer.

Anyone know how to do, or is that not possible with OpenLayer yet?

Here is the basic code I use to add the scale on the map: openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/controls/scaleline.html

Here is the code I use to export the map: openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/export-map.js

Thank you in advance for your response

Comment: When you export a map as PNG, you are exporting the map canvas. The scaleline, that you see on the map, is not drawn on the map canvas. It is a separate div container, so you can not export it currently with ol3.

Comment: it's possible to make a png from the canvas of the div container who containt the scaleline ?

Comment: To clarify: The scaleline is really just a div with some CSS styles, so there is no canvas. You can try to manually paint the scaleline on your PNG.

Comment: Have you thought of phantomJS, a headless browswer that allows you to do screen capture. http://phantomjs.org/, more specifically, http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: ok i'll try to paint the scaleline on my png ^^ thanks for response . phantomsJS would increase the weight of my site i thinks

Comment: What you could try is draw your own scale line in the map canvas in a postcompose listener.

Comment: can you show me a example ?

Comment: I did  what erilem suggested. 
See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083616/ (with Demo)